# What Year does "Cat in the Hat" (2003) Take Place?

Tags: the-cat-in-the-hat

What Year Does *The Cat in the Hat* starring Mike Myers take place? Since it's never made clear, is it supposed to be timeless?

The Clothing styles range from the 1920s to modern, most of the Cars are from the early 2000s, and all the buildings look like they are from the 1950s to 1960s.

Comment: Somebody's gonna end up having to do a whole piece on Seuss's artwork for this one... Basically, he drew either fantasy, sci-fi or pseudo-alpine victorian, or hard-to-place 'between the wars' architecture. He rarely ever used straight lines, which makes the houses in that movie a bit out-of-normal, but they still manage to achieve a hard to place 30's-50's look.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable. It's set in a fantasy world, with some elements and styles picked at random from our world. It's like asking what year _Star Wars_ or _Zootopia_ was supposed to take place.

Comment: Why was this voted to closure on POB? I don't think the OP is interested in any opinion. He wants a fact based cannon answer of in which era was the movie based. What's opinion based in that

Comment: @BrettFromLA Then that's...the answer (together with the previous comment)? I don't see how this makes the question remotely "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: @BrettFromLA   Star Wars (1977) obviously happens before 1977 since it took years to make and the opening credits say it happened "long ago in a galaxy far, far, away".  Thus Star Wars has no known year but must happen sometime between the big bang over 13,000,000,000 years ago and 42 years ago.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Perhaps "primarily opinion-based" is the wrong reason for closure. It just seems like a nonsense question because I don't think the filmmakers gave any thought to the year _Cat in the Hat_ took place. Since I respect your integrity and clout in this community, I'll ask: should I retract my close vote?

Comment: @BrettFromLA I don't know, as the comments on this question already suggest, there seems to be quite some thought put into how the film's setting *looks*, be that by the filmmakers or Dr. Seuss, which is ultimately what this question is about.

Comment: @BrettFromLA You don't have to retract your close-vote on my bidding, though. *I* don't see how it's justified. But if you do, you don't have to retract it just because I say so.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is answerable. It's set in a fantasy world, with some elements and styles picked at random from our world. I can't imagine the filmmakers ever saying to one another, "We're setting this film solidly in the year XXXX, so let's make sure the technology, architecture, and styles are consistent with that year."

This applies to other year-less films as well.  *Star Wars* and *Zootopia* come to mind.

Comment: This doesn't really adress the stark contrast between the styles of cars, clothing and architecture mentioned in the question. Such a variety is rather significant and comparing it to an utter and complete fantasy world like *Star Wars* seems a bit of a cop-out. As to *Zootopia*, that seems for all intents and purposes set in a modern or near-future world, judging by the *visual design*. Now if the buildings and clothes in *Zootopia* would look like from the 50s and Judy Hopps was still using an iPhone, that would make for an interesting question, too.

Comment: I like your take on this, @NapoleonWilson.